# Why my android app not showing in google play for tablet and few devices?

Tags: android

I have released my app for both mobile and tablet, but not showing up in google play for tablet and few mobile.
I have my manifest :

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You have `minSdkVersion="16"` . Do you know what this means? Or your question is about something else?

Comment: yah. I have minSdkVersion="16", because I have used fragment. Question is why not showing in tablet?

Comment: Question is "why not tablet and few devices". This was for the few devices part and you can still use fragments and support lower sdk versions, in the meantime. Take a look at here http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Comment: Since you are using Min SDK version 16. Devices running ICS won't be able to install your App. Tablets like Micromax Funbook and many others run on ICS, so they won't install your App. Try changing API level to 14 or below. Use Support library to support fragments there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here how Google Play filters apps:
http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html

Basically it uses the AndroidManifest.xml file to decide if your device can run your app.
It could be either one of these:

```
<supports-screens>
<uses-configuration>
<uses-feature>
<uses-library>
<uses-permission>
<uses-sdk>
```

In your case, it could be a tablet that might not have auto focus, or has a lower sdk version (lower than 16)

Another option is your settings inside Google Play. There you can decide for which countries the app is available for. This too can cause the app not to show for different users (Even if you're in the same location, the device's Google Play version might be registered under a different country)

Answer (score 0):

I think they get filtered by whatever device you are on at the time.  Are you searching using the type of device you want it to appear for?

Answer (score 0):

Have you designed seprate layouts for tabs?
and while uploading your app have you selected tablet option?

Comment: Ok then you can try Alok's method then